# Flask SocketIO messages not received

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, websocket

I am new to Flask and the IO. I'm trying to implement a basic data receiver for a machine with RoS. I have a python script sending data to a web server running on Flask.
The issue is that the java-script callback is never called and thus the numbers are strangely never added to the list, even though there are no errors.
The relevant parts are this:

Within Python Webserver:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    print("CALLED")

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
```

It is supposed to post a random number defined by the following Ros Callback function (This is called every 0.5s):

```
def forklift_callback(self, msg):
    #SOCKET TEST

    number = random.randint(1,101)
    print(number)
    socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/test')
```

Perhaps the way I define it is important:

```
*import statements*
from std_msgs.msg import String, UInt32
from umd_msgs.msg import PCNotification, RoverStatus, Barcode


mod = Blueprint('api', __name__)
msg = String()
started = "robot started"

socketio = SocketIO(app)
... All functionality ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

This is connected to the html page at the following location:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //connect to the socket server.
        console.log('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test')
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
            var numbers_received = [];

            //receive details from server
            socket.on('newnumber', function(msg) {
            console.log("Blank")
                console.log("Received number" + msg.number);
                //maintain a list of ten numbers
                if (numbers_received.length >= 10){
                    numbers_received.shift()
                }
                numbers_received.push(msg.number);
                numbers_string = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < numbers_received.length; i++){
                    numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + numbers_received[i].toString() + '</p>';
                }
                $('#log').html(numbers_string);
            });

        });
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Asynchronous Flask Communication</h1>
    <p>Random numbers generated by the Flask server will appear below, asynchronously.</p>

  </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <p>Asynchronous page updates will appear here:</p>
        <h3>Number list:</h3>
        <div id="log">
        </div> <!-- /#log -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethin like this,maybe it helps

You can do it with Thread that will run your function

```
yourThread = Thread()
thread_stop_event = Event()

class someClass(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    self.delay = 1
    super(someClass,self).__init__()

  def forklift_callback(self):
    while not thread_stop_event.isSet():           
      number = random.randint(1,101)
      print(number)
      socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/test')
      sleep(self.delay)

  def run(self):
    self.forklift_callback()

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
  print("CALLED")

  global yourThread
  if(not yourThread.isAlive()):
    yourThread = someClass()
    yourThread.start()
```

or just run it after client connects your server

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
  //your function here
  print("CALLED")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It turns out I had to uninstall gevent because it was interfering with the socket.